# JRockit product differences (Mission Control/Real time)

Tags: tomcat, jrockit

The detailed differences between the jrockit downloads available:

Oracle JRockit Mission Control and Oracle JRockit Real Time  *(Version 4.x)

Anyone faced any issues in testing Jrockit with Tomcat (Version 7.x or 5.x?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no technical differences between the packages, only licensing terms may differ.